# ember.js filter items in array in view

Tags: ember.js

I have a site I am working on that contains minimal data and am fine with making very few actual DB calls to fetch the data. I have a view the separates items out by type and would like to only display the items that match that type in the corresponding list.

I have a few different divs that contain the item types and would like to display a list of items that correspond to that type.

```
<div>
 <p>hammers</p>
 <ul>
 li>hammer 1</li>
 </ul>
</div>


<div>
  <p>pencils</p>
  <ul>
     <li>graphite</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So basically anything matching the type of hammers would be displayed in that list and enumerated through the end of all the matches to that type.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter using `Ember.computed.filter` or `Ember.computed.filterBy`.

```
var view = Ember.View.extend({
     items: [],
     hammers: Ember.computed.filterBy('items', 'type', 'hammer'),
     pencils: Ember.computed.filterBy('items', 'type', 'pencil')
});
```

Comment: this is a nice feature! I would have done this using computed properties and filtering within it

Comment: I am precompiling my templates. Would I put this in a view? I am fairly new to ember.js and am building this application as a learning exercise for myself.

Comment: This goes wherever you have your list of items. It can go it a model, controller, view or component. If you're not using any custom views or components, it should probably be in the controller.

Comment: nice, the returned array is a **live** view.